# Wildcard subdomains for all domains

Tags: apache-2.2, wildcard-subdomain

So what I have at the moment (for each domain) is this

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 

  ServerName exmaple.com
  ServerAlias *.example.com

  DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
  VirtualDocumentRoot /srv/www/example.com/public_html/%0

</VirtualHost>
```

But I'd like to save having to ever duplicate this for another domain by doing something like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 

  ServerName *
  ServerAlias *

  DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
  VirtualDocumentRoot /srv/www/%2+/public_html/%0

</VirtualHost>
```

%2+ being all but the subdomain.
Is this even possible…

Answer (score 1):

As long as you'd only have single-level subdomains, then that should work.  If you want to serve all your pages via `mod_vhost_alias`, just take the `VirtualDocumentRoot` line out of the `<VirtualHost>` directives, and eliminate all your `<VirtualHost>` directives.

You don't need to specify the wildcard `ServerName`.  It requires a FQDN anyway, so you can't use one anyway.  Similarly with `ServerAlias`, since `VirtualDocumentRoot` is taking care of finding the right places to serve pages from, it's not necessary to use since the `Host:` header will be processed dynamically.

Reading the docs on [mod_vhost_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html) and [Dynamically configured mass virtual hosting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/mass.html) should help clear up any remaining confusion.